# How to display articles based on composed tag

Tags: search, tags

I'm encountering an issue when I want to display some articles based on a "composed" tag like "amnesty-international". The query doesn't return any results. The fact is I have two article tagged with this slug.
This is the code I use in the template archive.php:

```
$current_tag =  single_term_title("", false);
$args= array(
    'post_type' => 'adverts',
    'tag' => $current_tag
);

$adsQuery = new WP_Query($args);
```

So this url doesnt return anything : http://www.mydomain.net/tag/amnesty-international/

Should I use another function ?

Comment: `single_term_title` doesn't return slugs. It returns **titles**. It will return "Howdy Ho" instead of "howdy-ho'. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54544/filter-query-posts-by-tag-slug-on-tag-archive-page-when-tag-is-2-or-more-word

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude Specific Term from Search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41069/exclude-specific-term-from-search)

Comment: @s_ha_dum Thx for your explanation, the topic did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a similar topic I can do it with :

```
$tag       = get_queried_object();
$tag_slug  = $tag->slug;
```

Or with this snippet :

```
$current_tag =  single_term_title("", false);
tag_slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $current_tag);
```